# Customizing About dialog of RCP applications beyond changing text and image

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to override the standard `AboutDialog` provided by RCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not a lot you can do via customizations - beyond text and image as you mention - so the "easy" solution is to create your own version instead. Depending on the changes you want, this is not all that difficult. If you want to re-use parts of the old dialog - e.g. the feature group list - then you can probably get through via a fragment.

Comment: Under Windows/Linux, that's not a problem: I just put the command which shows my dialog into Help menu instead of`org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction`. However, how can I get my dialog to show in the Mac application menu?